# Xcode debug view hierarchy but stuck at capturing user interface

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode   debug view hierarchy but stuck at capturing user interface

wait long time ，but no result

Xcode 12.2
macOS 10.15.7

want to konw:
1.How to solve the problem?
2.Why is this a problem?

Comment: This can only happen on real machines，my test phone is iPhone 7

Comment: I everyday facing this problem with our big project and till now I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I face this problem for long time. Still stuck here. Any update?

Answer (score 0):

It's happened to me before quite a few times, but hitting the capture user interface button a second time usually works (you'll have to wait a few seconds before Xcode responds back... it sucks I know ). Another thing would be hitting the Run button again but that's the longest path tough...

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I face this problem for a long time. Do you know any other way to workaround?